# 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem

Tags: c#, wpf

What i have so far :

```
  private void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(PublicVar.ConnectionString);
        con1.Open();
        #endregion


        SqlCommand  ss = new SqlCommand("Select MorabiName From MorabiTable", con1);
        SqlDataReader s = ss.ExecuteReader();




        while (s.Read())

        {
            MorabiComboBox.Items.Add(s[0]).ToString();
        }
    }
```

And what i have for find ComboBoxItem Value

```
  if (this.MorabiComboBox == null)
            return;

        var combo = (ComboBox)sender;
        var selectedValue = (ComboBoxItem)combo.SelectedValue;
        SQLToRun SQLtoRun = new SQLToRun();
        MorabiID = await SQLtoRun.SQLToString(PublicVar.ConnectionString, "Select (MorabiID) from MorabiTable where MorabiName = ") + selectedValue;
```

but when i build program it show me error on line 
`var selectedValue = (comboBoxItem)combo.selectedValue` and tell

> $exception {"Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem'."}   System.InvalidCastException

What I should do else?

Comment: Please note that WPF is meant to be used with the MVVM pattern. Ignoring it might technically work, but you will always struggle. Get a good book or tutorial on WPF and MVVM and questions like this won't pop up in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly this `ToString` statement is completely redundant

```
MorabiComboBox.Items.Add(s[0]).ToString();
```

Secondly `combo.SelectedValue` is string, look at the line above. Casting it to a `ComboBoxItem` doesn't make any sense. Look at the name `SelectedValue` it tells you what it is.

The following would make more sense

```
var selectedValue = (string)combo.SelectedValue
```

Lastly,

Consider using `Parameterized Queries` and not concatinating strings to make SQL queries

Comment: if i change comboboxitem to string , can i use use Combo.SelectedValue Again?

Comment: @RezaPak please define what you mean by using it again

Answer (score 2):

If you want a `ComboBoxItem`, then create one in your `Grid_Loaded` event handler:

```
MorabiComboBox.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem { Content = s[0].ToString() });
```

You could then cast the `SelectedItem` property to a `ComboBoxItem`:

```
var selectedValue = combo.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem:
```

If you add a string to the `Items` collection, you should cast the `SelectedItem` property to a `string`:

```
var selectedValue = combo.SelectedItem as string;
```

The types must match.

Answer (score 0):

```
 MorabiComboBox.Items.Add(s[0].ToString());
```

Use this and its gonna work this time.